# I'm trying to connect my java project with db, error No suitable driver found (I use libgdx gradle)

Tags: java, mysql, libgdx

I am trying to link my project to the db with xampp and phpmyadmin but I get this error:

No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test;databaseName=test;user=root;password=

```
package com.mygdx.game.tools;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DataBase {

    private String url;
    private Connection conn;

    public DataBase(String address, String dbname, String dbuser, String password){
       this.url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + address + ";databaseName=" + dbname + ";user=" + dbuser + ";password=" + password;
       this.conn = null;
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException{
       this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url);
    }

    public void close() throws SQLException{
       this.conn.close();
    }

    public void save(String username, int points) throws SQLException{
       PreparedStatement pst = this.conn.prepareStatement("insert into scores(username,points) values(?,?");
       pst.setString(1, username);
       pst.setInt(2, points);
       pst.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

And in my main class:

```
try{
   String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";  //Maybe is this the url
   String dbname = "test";
   String user = "root";
   String password = "";
   DataBase db = new DataBase(url,dbname,user,password);
   db.open();
   db.save(textField.getText(),punteggio);
   System.exit(0);
   db.close();
}catch(SQLException e){
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Database constructor uses a jdbc:sqlserver: subprotocol for MS-Server, but actually that is added in front of a jdbc:mysql: MySQL database URL. You must modify Database. Also close the PreparedStatement.

```
/** @return the update count. */
public int save(String username, int points) throws SQLException {
   try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("""
           insert into scores(username, points)
           values(?, ?)
       """)) {
       pst.setString(1, username);
       pst.setInt(2, points);
       return pst.executeUpdate();
    } // Closes pst.
}
```

Comment: It says is not supported

Comment: Multiline string """ ... """ (useful for SQL) is relative new in java, you can use "...." without line breaks. _(I think that is what is not supported.)_

Comment: The try-with-resources was also missing a closing `)`.

Comment: Ok the code work but i still have the error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test;databaseName=test;user=root;password=

Comment: You would need to remove `"jdbc:sqlserver://" + `  but then old code on MS SQL would fail.

Comment: If i connected the database via mysql-connection, could it work without entering address?

Comment: Maybe the driver..

Comment: The Database class does little; you could make a copy and change it a bit.

Comment: I forgot to mention it. I use netbeans and libgdx library... It doesn't work

Comment: Then let forget this question & answer. Maybe write a bit of test code, just with java Standard Edition calls, and when that does not work, ask a new question.